# Wordpress: After multi-site, it is now redirected on the management screen

Tags: php, wordpress

I made Wordpress multi-site, and I can no longer access the management screen on the following page.
The management screen of the site `http://example.com/` that originally existed when it became a multi-site cannot be accessed, and the following url appears and redirects.     This is a newly created site
You can log in to the management screen of `http://example.com/sub`.
The login ID is the same for both the subsite and the original site.

**What you want to achieve**
Log in from `http://example.com/admin`.

**Problems / error messages that are occurring**.
The management screen of the following url is displayed

```
https://example.com?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Flemon-site.work%2Fwp%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

**What I tried**.
Add the following to wp-config.php.

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
```